# Revoke READ access to objects after upload

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to implement "one-way" log-files backup scheme with Google Cloud Storage: service account should be able to upload objects via gsutil rsync, but should not be able to download these objects after that?

All canned ACLs imply requester will OWNER role to uploaded objects

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's not simple. GCS's ownership model irrevocably grants ownership to the account that uploaded an object. In order for you to upload an object without keeping read access, you'll need to be a little creative.

First option: have your logger request a signed URL from another administrative account. When you use a signed URL to upload an object, the account that generated that URL owns the object, not the uploader. This allows you to vend signed URLs to a user that can be used for uploaded but can't later be used to read the object back.

Second option: move the object. While the original object is owned by the uploader, if the object is copied elsewhere and the original is deleted, the account that did the copying is the new owner. You can even copy the object over itself to the same object name. You could use Google Cloud Pub/Sub notifications or Google Cloud Functions to set up a small trigger that, whenever an object is uploaded to a bucket, copies that object over itself to change the ownership.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. I'm going to use gsutil rsync for the second option. If original object will be replaced with the same object name, does backuper account be able to read object metadata next time?